# Создание новой страницы

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос. Делаю интернет-магазин. Не хочу возиться с созданием каждый раз новой страницы для своего товара. Потому что товара очень много, и каждый раз писать в ручную новую страницу затруднительно. Можно ли создать форму через которую я буду заполнять свой сайт товаром, что бы после обработки создавалась новая страница но уже с другим товаром, с его фотографиями и своими характеристиками. Все характеристики для каждого товара разные. Так же есть база данных в которой будут все товары. Спасибо большое за внимание, и за ответы. Огромная просьба не писать не по теме, те кто не знает ответа показывайте свой острый юмор в другом месте. Спасибо.

Comment: почитайте про движки сайтов (wordpress/joomla/drupal), движки магазинов/плагины для  сайтов (opencart, например)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так все правильно. Создавайте страницу программно через php, используйте шаблоны, в которых можно заменять динамически информацию. Допустим есть товар(пусть его `id` = 56), тогда при клике на него должна открываться страница `http://example.com/index.php?product_id=56`, в которой по `product_id` из базы данных достается нужная информация. 

По поводу шаблона.
Пусть есть стандартная разметка(основная):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>...</head>
   <body>
   <!--тут какие нибудь блоки-->
   <div>{product}</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

`{product}` это та часть, которая будет динамически изменяться.

**Пример**
У нас есть общая точка входа - `index.php`:

```
<?php
    $product_id = (int) $_GET['product_id'];

    //здесь прочие запросы к бд
```

Где через `GET` запрос мы получаем идентификатор товара, в последствии делаем запрос на получение детальной его информации(описание, картинки).

Чтобы обрабатывать `{product}` вам придется написать шаблонизатор, который будет заменять `{product}` на еще одну `html` разметку, которая будет описывать товар.

Это все кажется запутанным для новичка, но это очень сильно упростит работу, т.к. скрипты отдельно, вёрстка отдельно.

Comment: Ну тут ещё проблема в том что страница ещё должна быть визуально красива, у меня мысли сделать определённый каркас страницы, и что бы просто в этот каркас заполнялась информация которая будет не только в базе данных. К примеру наврятли стоит заливать в базу данных описание предмета, и картинки.

Comment: @Sambl, так я и предлагаю использовать шаблон, где только часть страницы будет иметь динамический характер.

Comment: получается одна часть будет динамической а остальную придутся вручную добавлять? тогда вообще не понимаю как это реализовать, потому что товара будет очень много. Я предполагал что под каждый товар будет создана отдельная страница, и поэтому и спросил можно ли через форму создавать новую страницу в которой часть уже будет брать данные из базы а чать будет заполнена мной, но при этом товар будет иметь свою отдельную страничку

Comment: Вы через форму в бд можете добавлять любую информацию. А потом только 1 раз ее вытаскивать. Запросов много не будет.

Comment: @Sambl ты только определись сначала, что ты делать хочешь, продавать или программировать

Answer (score 1):

Не следует генерировать статические HTML-страницы и складировать их - их сложно обновлять, их трудно отдавать. У вас под детальную страницу товара в принципе должна быть только один PHP-файл. Он средствами PHP должен генерировать HTML-код, под каждый тип товара - разный код.

Более того, в настоящий момент принято, чтобы у вас со стороны приложения была одна точка входа, на которую сервер передает роут, например, /catalog/cars или /catalog/cars/534. Приложение разбирает роут и выполняет соответствующий ему PHP-код. Соответствие может быть задано таблицей база данных или конфигурационным файлом или просто соглашением. PHP-код в зависимости от типа страниц (главная, индексная каталога, детальная товара, страница поиска и т.п.) и идентификатора товара генерирует представление (HTML) соответствующей страницы.

Большинство CMS и фреймворков строится именно по этой схеме. Много точек входа - много точек отказа, их сложнее тестировать.

Comment: Ну данный тип используется если просто мы вытаскиваем информацию с базы данных, но не вижу смысла загружать в базу картинки или описание предмета. На многих интернет магазинах видел что в ссылке сверху нету запроса в базу данных а ссылка выглядит так (название сайта.ru/наименование товара)

Comment: Вам не обязательно каждый раз обращаться к базе данных, вы можете складировать сгенерированную информацию в мемкэшд и изменять ее только тогда, когда она меняется в системе администрирования. Просто если вы завяжетесь на жесткий диск, вы себе здорово усложните задачу оптимизации и масштабирования сайта в будущем. При работе через PHP-файл вы себе развязываете руки. Повторю, вы можете не лазить в базу данных, можете работать через кэш.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо создать единую точку входа(маршрутизатор). Где будут разбираться url.
Например, вы хотите получить товар с id равным 100. 
Ссылка будет иметь вид [http://ваш_сайт/маршрутизатор?id=100](http://%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80?id=100).
Далее в маршрутизаторе разбираем url(в данном случае GET запрос) и подтягиваем товар с нужным id из базы данных.
Как-то так. На пальцах если. И без ЧПУ.

Comment: Ну тут ещё проблема в том что страница ещё должна быть визуально красива, у меня мысли сделать определённый каркас страницы, и что бы просто в этот каркас заполнялась информация которая будет не только в базе данных. К примеру наврятли стоит заливать в базу данных описание предмета, и картинки.

Comment: Если вы не хотите создавать шаблон для каждого товара отдельно, то тогда вам придется подтягивать и описание предмета и урл картинок из БД. То есть всю текстовую информацию придется хранить в базе данных.

Comment: я тоже так думал. Просто наткнулся на ряд интернет магазинов в ссылках которых не было запроса а ссылка выглядела просто (название магазина.ru/название товара) но не думаю что он создавал каждый раз новую страницу, так как на сайте около 3000 товаров

Comment: Это ЧПУ(человеко-понятные-урл).Там как угодно можно называть товары.Если все настроить правильно

Answer (score 0):

для интернет магазина есть куча cms, одна из них magento среди ecommerce платформ удобна как для программистов так и для простых людей, и имеет кучу настроек из коробки + сео + маркетинговые правила и т.д. и т.п. не пилите что то сами, так как и времени много уйдёт, сил и нервов, и тем более это уже есть бесплатно в opersource, по теме скажу лиш то что лучше пока взять 1.9 версию.
https://magento.com/